# How to place two (or multiple) figures in a row with same height in ConTeXt?

Tags: context, context-mkiv

I need to place several figures with different aspect ratios in a row using `ConTeXt`. I also need their heights to be equal, but summary width of pictures to be `\textwidth`. Height of pictures must calculated authomatically, pictures must be glued exactly side-to-side.

like

```
-----------------------------
|pic1|   wide pic2   | pic3 |
----------------------------- 
|        \textwidth         |
|<------------------------->|
```

How ?

Comment: There was a post with `\startcombination` solution, but it was deleted. This works just like I need if `\setupcombination[distance=0mm]` (no `width=\textwidth`) and `\startcombination` wrapped in `\scale[width=\textwidth]{}`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `combination` and (from comments) `\scale`. Note that if you add captions to each image, as in the below code, this text will be scaled as well.

[image]

```
\setupcombination[distance=0mm]
\starttext
\input knuth

\scale[width=\textwidth]{\startcombination[3*1]
{\externalfigure[example-image.pdf][height=3cm]}{text}
{\externalfigure[example-image-10x16.pdf][height=3cm]}{under}
{\externalfigure[example-image-16x10.pdf][height=3cm]}{image}
\stopcombination}

\input knuth

\stoptext
```

Comment: Pictures must be glued edge-to-edge. Their height must be calculated automatically, not manually.

Comment: This also scales the captions

Comment: @Aditya Thanks for the note. (I actually meant to remove them, as the question doesn't mention captions, but I'll add a note about that in the answer.)

Answer (score 2):

The solution can be achieved in two steps:

1. Create a box in which the height of all the images is the same (does not matter what this height is)
2. Scale the box so that its width equals textwidth.

Here is an example:

```
% Example images
\useexternalfigure[kitten1][http://placekitten.com/g/200/300][method=jpg]
\useexternalfigure[kitten2][http://placekitten.com/g/200/400][method=jpg]
\useexternalfigure[kitten3][http://placekitten.com/g/200/500][method=jpg]


\starttext

\subject{Images without any scaling}

\dontleavehmode
\externalfigure[kitten1]\externalfigure[kitten2]\externalfigure[kitten3]

\subject{Images scaled to textwidth}

\scale[width=\textwidth]
  {\externalfigure[kitten1][height=1cm]%
   \externalfigure[kitten2][height=1cm]%
   \externalfigure[kitten3][height=1cm]}

\stoptext
```

which gives

[image]